# Flutter, how to change listview item size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have row(horizontal) listview which are texts

and code is something like this

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (pageNumber != null) {
              pageNum = pageNumber - 1;
              _bigSizeNum = pageNumber - 1;
              _rightIndex = false;
              _rowListContainerWidth =
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04;
              _rowListContainerHeight =
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08;
            }
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 140),
          width: _rowListContainerWidth,
          height: _rowListContainerHeight,
          margin: _rightIndex
              ? EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 0,
                )
              : EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 0,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 0.6,
              color: Colors.white70,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(4),
            ),
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              pageNumber.toString(),
              softWrap: false,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

and _rowListContainerWidth size is not working at all

because I guess the only itemExtent makes a decision to how to set width size !

[image]

my temperor solution was make a margin so it looks like smaller

but the space margin are so annoying I think this is all because of itemExtent

I want the space blanks are having all same size between items. thank you

Comment: @Benjamin Corben thanks but this is not a row this is a listview

Comment: any chance to edit your code so we can reproduce your question by simple copy - paste technique..... help us - help you

Comment: @LonelyWolf thanks do you mean that want more simple code?

Comment: * space blanks are having all same size between items* means you want to remove empty space?

Comment: @Blasanka I mean all spaces should equally have same size

Comment: @aumdlaqe So,  you can try adding `ListView`s `ItemExtent` custom value.

Answer (score 0):

make the margin only at the left side

```
          margin: _rightIndex
              ? EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 0,
                )
              : EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 0,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04)
```